# Running Vim in shell script opens rest of shell script in a buffer

Tags: buffers, shell

I've got Vim starting in a shell script to install some plugins. I'm using `nvim --headless +PlugInstall +qall`, but when Vim opens, it has the rest of the shell script (`cd $HOME/.config/coc/extensions && yarn install &> /dev/null`) open in a buffer. How can I prevent this?

Script:

```
clear
echo 'Backing up old Vim config...' 
mv $HOME/.vimrc $HOME/.vimrc_back &> /dev/null
mv $HOME/.vim/ $HOME/.vim_back &> /dev/null
mv $HOME/.config/coc/ $HOME/.config/coc_back &> /dev/null
echo 'Downloading VDE...'
git clone https://github.com/-----/----- $HOME/VDE &> /dev/null
echo 'Setting up VDE...'
mv $HOME/VDE/src/.vimrc $HOME/.vimrc &> /dev/null
mv $HOME/VDE/src/.vim $HOME/.vim &> /dev/null
mv $HOME/VDE/src/coc $HOME/.config/coc &> /dev/null
rm -rf $HOME/VDE &> /dev/null
nvim --headless +PlugInstall +qall
cd $HOME/.config/coc/extensions && yarn install &> /dev/null
cd $HOME
nvim --headless +CocRebuild +qall
```

Comment: Added the script, though I've already managed to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by adding `&> /dev/null` to the `nvim --headless +PlugInstall +qall` command